# CSS Custom Outline on Button Focus

Tags: html, css, button, outline

My HTML is structured like this:

```
<li>
  <button/>
</li>
```

I'm trying to create an outline on a button when it's focused, but I have the following specifications:

1. It cannot add any width to the enclosing `<li>`
2. I don't want to outline the bottom of the button, only the left/right/top

Any suggestions on how to go about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [`:focus` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) along with [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

```css
button:focus {
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0) 0 -2px 5px 1px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <button>click to show outline</button>
</li>
```

Comment: @tcanbolat I don't see any mention of `border` in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Outline can appear only from all four sides of an element, so try to remove default outline and then add box shadow to get desirable result.

```css
button:focus {
  outline: none; /* to remove default outline */
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 1px red; /* use box-shadow to emulate outlining */
}
```